# change image background on single page wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

i have a page with the ID page "68" and i would like change the background of this page.

I've try this but doesnt work...

```
.page-id-68 > img#fsb_image {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

or this

```
.page-id-68 {
background-image:url(https://laportedessecrets.fr/wpcontent/uploads/202003/Photo-escalier-livre.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Do you have any idea ??

Comment: Including your `HTML` and maybe a link to the live page would help.

Comment: Your image is not loading

Comment: I'not a fan of  `!important` but I thing it might be a solution for your problem. `background-image:url(https://laportedessecrets.fr/wpcontent/uploads/202003/Photo-escalier-livre.jpg)!important;`

Comment: unfortunaly it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use this code:

```css
.post-id-68 {
background: #000000;
}
```

or If you want to add an image in the background then you can use:

```css
.post-id-68 {
background: url('image path');
} 

or

.post-id-68 {
background-image: url('image path');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this also?

```css
body.post-id-68 {
background: url('image path');
}
```

Comment: The CSS is called or not?
Maybe is another CSS was overriding to this CSS?

Comment: yes i think my css is not called, how i can correct this ??

Comment: Try this also?

body.post-id-68 {
background: url('image path') !important;
}

Comment: Can you please check in body, this class is available or not: post-id-68